# How to prevent kivy from logging into file

Tags: python, kivy

so I would like to prevent kivy from writing a log when running my program.

How do I do that?

Heres a picture of what I want to stop:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBJ4h.png

I've already tried doing

```py
Config.set('kivy', 'log_enable', '0')
```

but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your first `py` file, put:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_NO_FILELOG'] = '1'  # eliminate file log
os.environ['KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG'] = '1'  # eliminate console log
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/environment.html#configuration).